# How to build tesseract4.0 from source code in windows using cmake?

Tags: c++, build, cmake, tesseract, leptonica

I already tried the pre-compiled Leptonica binary link but I read [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/120472/how-to-build-opencv-32-text-module-with-tesseract-40/) that I have to build this from source only. So I tried building Leptonica from source.

I downloaded the source code of Leptonica from this [link].(https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) Then I tried to build this code using CMake. To build I used CMake GUI. In source-code path I gave where `CMakeLists.txt` is located and in cross compiling option I gave this `scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake` from this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg).

But I am getting this error

```
CMake Error at C:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:247 (_find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Leptonica" (requested version 1.74) with any of the following names:

    LeptonicaConfig.cmake
    leptonica-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "Leptonica" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"Leptonica_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.
If "Leptonica" provides a separate development package or SDK,
be sure it has been installed.
```

For this I build leptonica separately and generated this `LeptonicaConfig.cmake` file as asked in this error. But now I have to change the `CMakeLists.txt` and set `Leptonica_DIR` to the directory where my this `LeptonicaConfig.cmake` located. I don't know how to do this I tried adding  this line in cmakelists file `set(Leptonica_DIR="C:\Leptonica")`. But this doesn't work, may be this is wrong.

I am really stuck, I am using **`tesseract4.0`** and **`Leptonica 17.6`** and really new to this building process.

Comment: Use of vcpkg, open source packager, will make the installation super easy.

Comment: If you want to set `Leptonica_DIR` variable, set it in the GUI. Note, that variable should point to the directory, which *directly* contains `LeptonicaConfig.cmake` file. Alternatively, you may add installation prefix of "Leptonica" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable, as the error message suggests. This also could be done in CMake GUI.

Comment: According to the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), if you have **installed** `leptonica`, then the `LeptonicaConfig.cmake` ends up under `[path-to-root-install-dir-of-your-choice]/leptonica/cmake/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot now I am using this, it works https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git